# Qt TabWidget corner widget size

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets

Have some problem with corner widget due using non-standard font size in app, screenshot to be clear:

[image]

code:

```
QToolButton* m_exit = new QToolButton(m_tab);
m_exit->setIcon(QIcon(":/Resources/exit.png"));
m_exit->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum, QSizePolicy::Maximum);
m_tab->setCornerWidget(m_exit, Qt::TopRightCorner);
```

font changing via

```
QApplication::setFont(...);
```

How can i do corner button same size as tab-buttons size?

P.S. using `setStyleSheet( "QTabBar::tab { min-height: 120px; }" );` not allowed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`::right-corner`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#right-corner-sub) sub-control in your stylesheet. There you can set the height of the corner button (you'd probably have to adjust the bottom too). Set both heights (corner button and tab) to the same value.

```
QTabWidget::right-corner {
    height: 30px;
    bottom: 10px;
}

QTabBar::tab {
    height: 30px;
}
```